# regular expression for log

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a log file like this:

```
some strings...
<FX>
another strings...
<FX s='asdf' asd="ascvas">
<TEG1>
  <TEG2>
  </TEG2>
</TEG1>
</FX>
some strings...
</FX>
some strings...
<FX>
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>    

<FX>
<CLR>
</CLR>
</FX>
end of file
</FX>
```

I need to write on vbscript regular expression to parse it and get this results:

```
<FX s='asdf' asd="ascvas">
    <TEG1>
      <TEG2>
      </TEG2>
    </TEG1>
</FX>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>    
<FX>
    <CLR>
    </CLR>
</FX>
```

I have already wrote this expression:

```
(<\?xml[^>]*>[\s\S]*)*<\s*FX[^>]*>((?!<\s*FX[^>]*>)[\s\S])*<\s*/\s*FX\s*>
```

But it doesn't work correct with tag /FX. You could view rezult here:
http://regexr.com?341ps

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Vlad L. Yes, the requirements change :)

Answer (score 0):

Change it this way:

```
^\<\?xml[^>]*>[\s\S]*<\s*FX[^>]*>((?!<\s*FX[^>]*>)[\s\S])*<\s*/\s*FX\s*>
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
/(<[^\s]+\s+\w=[^>]+>[^/]+\/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^>]+>)|(<\?xml[^/]+/[^/]+/[^>]+>)/m
# http://regexr.com?386si


/(<[^\s]+\s+\w=[^>]+>[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^>]+>)|(<\?xml[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^>]+>)/m
# (escaped forward slash)
# http://rubular.com/r/SwI2vz6ctk
```

http://regexr.com?386si

http://rubular.com/r/SwI2vz6ctk